# Having trouble with the error: expected unqualfied-id before '{' just a header for a class that I need just not sure what is causing the error

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
  {
    class book
    {
    public: 
        set_book();
        show_book();

    private:
        string title,author;
        int pages,date;
    };  
  }
```

Comment: Start by including `<string>`. And do you really mean to have the class inside that scope block?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing includes (`string`), you should avoid `using namespace std` in a header.

And also, remove this extra scope :

```
using namespace std;
// { <------
class book
{
public: 
    set_book();
    show_book();

private:
    string title,author;
    int pages,date;
};  
// } <------
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points made by other answers...

You have:

```
    set_book();
    show_book();
```

These are not valid member function declarations. They need, at the least, a return type.

```
    void set_book();
    void show_book();
```

Please add any input arguments needed by them.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bogus set of `{` and `}`.

Change to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   // this is a bad idea BTW

class book
{
// etc.
```

Also it'd be a good idea to `#include <string>` in case whoever includes your file does not include that; and if you don't actually use `iostream` then don't include it.